# O que é considerado um elemento na Google Matrix Distance

Tags: google-maps

Eu estou a desenvolver um software que necessita de obter informações através da API Google Matriz Distance.
O problema é que esta API tem limites de pedidos a 2500 elementos por dia.
Minha duvida é o que é um elemento?
Uma chamada a API é considerado um elemento?

Cumprimentos,
Leandro

Comment: Sim baseado nisto https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-limits#premium-usage-limits parece-me também que seja cada requisição feita

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A própria [documentação](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-limits#premium-usage-limits) já responde a sua pergunta:

> Each query sent to the Google Maps Distance Matrix API is limited by the number of allowed elements, where the number of origins times the number of destinations defines the number of elements.

Logo abaixo, temos os limites da API:

> Users of the standard API:
>
> - 2,500 free elements per day
> - Maximum of 25 origins or 25 destinations per request
> - 100 elements per query
> - 100 elements per 10 seconds

Ou seja, se por dia você pode buscar 2500 elementos e em cada *query* pode haver até 100 elementos, é possível efetuar no mínimo 25 *queries* por dia.

Também é bom notar que cada requisição pode ter um máximo de 25 origens ou 25 destinos, então nesse caso respectivamente elas estariam limitadas a 4 destinos ou 4 origens. (25 * 4 = 100)

Comment: Obrigado @Rodrigo Rigotti. Realmente não vi a primeira parte....
Agora ficou tudo claro.

Comment: Se resolveu seu problema, não esqueça de validar a resposta. :)